# Is it possible to connect a Discord or Microsoft Teams chatbot to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, discord.py

Wondering if it's possible to connect our chatbots to Google Analytics to get metrics on our chat servers in Discord and Microsoft teams. Would this be considered an "ISV"?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/integrate/isv

Comment: It's just a API so yes you can use it to integrate it with pretty much anything (how you integrate it is up to you), read that link better and study it more. But I'm pretty sure this is against Discord ToS.

Comment: Thanks, not here for legal discussion though. I comply with the applicable sections of the Discord API ToS in regards to this (Sections 2.2.v, 2.4, 2.5.c, 2.5.d, 2.5.f, and Section 13. https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/legal)